# Analytics API to check which bot visited

Tags: .net, api, google-analytics

Does anyone know how to find out which bot visited your website/page using google analytics API and .Net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ga:medium,ga:source" as dimension, "ga:visits" as metric and "ga:medium==organic" as filter.

A library for .NET can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/